# how to solve async-readfile-problem with fs in express?

Tags: express, async-await, fs

unfortunately i am far away from most people here in js-knowledge and have again and again the problem, to design the workflow of my app in a synchronously order!
the main thing - i dont understand to design something like this readfile-code in a simple way - that the code-parts coming under the block, where something is executed and (in this case) data loaded, dont get executed BEFORE the excecution in the block gets finished - and (like in this case) the data (sKey) remains undef although the console in the block itself confirms it defined correctly?!
probably its something specific with EXPRESS - but this js has to run in EXPRESS - whatever advice might help please!

```
'''const fsBase = require('fs');
const fs = fsBase.promises;
const fn = async () => {
    const data = await fs.readFile('example.txt', 'utf8');
    console.log("in readfile: " + data);
//works perfectly
    return data;
};
sKey = fn();
console.log("after readfile: " + sKey);
//returns sKey undef'''
```

Comment: In the code you posted, `sKey` is definitely not `undefined` but a promise. Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score -1):

You're suppose to get the data inside a callback function, rather than attempting to get it from return statements:

```
const fs=require('fs');

const fn = async () => {
    let data;
    await fs.readFile('example.txt', 'utf8',(err,data_)=>{
      data=data_;
    });
    console.log("in readfile: " + data);
    return data;
};
sKey=fn();
console.log("after readfile: " + sKey);
```

Comment: `fs.promises` methods do not take a callback.